# Tratamento de erros PHP PDO

Tags: php, pdo

Em PHP, como fazer para o PDO não emitir erro FATAL, de modo que seja possível identificar e tratar o erro ocorrido?

Exemplo:
Tabela: tb_pedidos:
id fk_produtos qtd
1  5           5
2  7           2
3  2           13

Tabela: tb_produtos
id descricao
5  Manga
7  Uva
2  Pêssego

Sendo que há **relacionamento** entre **tb_pedidos.fk_produtos** e **tb_produtos.id**.

Se tento excluir Manga (id = 5) da tabela **tb_produtos**...

```
$sql = "DELETE FROM tb_produtos where id = ?"; // query
$rs = $this->conn->prepare($sql); // prepara a query
$arParametros = array(5); // parametro(s) para a query
try {
  $teste = $rs->execute($arParametros); // executa query
} catch (PDOException $err) {// DEVERIA TRATAR EXCEÇÕES PDO
        echo "ERRO PDO.....<br/>";
        var_dump($err->getMessage());
        var_dump($this->conn->errorInfo());
        echo '...fim erros PDO....';
} catch (Exception $err) {// DEVERIA TRATAR OUTRAS EXCEÇÕES (NÃO PDO)
        echo "ERRO NÃO PDO.....<br/>";
        var_dump($err);
        echo "FIM ERRO NÃO PDO.....<br/>";
}
```

...porém, nunca entra no `CATCH`, gera o erro abaixo e a execução do script é encerrada:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails....

Como fazer para não encerrar a execução do script? Ou seja, entrar no CATCH e tornar possível o tratamento do erro?

Notas:

Na conexão utilizo:

```
$this->conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$this->conn->setAttribute(\PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Meu ambiente:

- PHP 5.6
- MySQL 5.5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439581/catching-multiple-exception-types-in-one-catch-block/19325523#19325523

Comment: i) Declarou o uso da classe *\PDOException*?  ii) `} catch (\PDOException $err) {`

Comment: @PapaCharlie Era exatamente isso, só colocar a barra invertida antes de PDOException.... muito obrigado! Se puder, posta a resposta que marco ela agora.

Comment: Isso serve pro `catch (Exception $err)` também. Toda classe eu declaro abaixo do namespace pra evitar ter de declarar com barra invertida e eventualmente um esquecimento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No caso de estar usando *namespace* deve-se declarar a classe com a barra invertida logo abaixo do *namespace*, `use \PDOException`, ou no próprio bloco do código `catch (\PDOException $err)`.

```
namespace XXX;
use \PDOException;
...
catch (PDOException $err)
```

ou

```
namespace XXX;
...
catch (\PDOException $err)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda!